# Flask application - delete function isn't working

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm building a simply flask application (CRUD app)

So far, I have managed to get input data from HTML page, save it to the SQLite DB and render it back to the page.

Now I want to render a delete button where I can click the button to delete the data, I wrote the code like this, I see no error when I click the button but also nothing has been deleted.

Can anyone spot any mistake or error, please?

```
@app.route('/users', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def users():
    if request.form.get("delete"):
        user_db = Users.query.filter_by(user_id=request.form.get("user_id")).first()
        db.session.delete(user_db)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect("user.html")

    if request.form:
        user_db = Users(user_name = request.form.get("user_name"),
                        age = request.form.get("age"),
                        gender=request.form.get("gender"),
                        activeness=request.form.get("activeness")
                        )
        db.session.add(user_db)
        db.session.commit()
    user_data = Users.query.all()
    return render_template("users.html", user_data = user_data)
```

---

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>User ID</th>
        <th>User name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Activeness<th>
    </tr>
    {% for i in user_data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ i.user_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.user_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.age }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.gender }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.activeness }}</td>
        <td><form method="POST" action="./users">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ i.user_id }}" name="user_id">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete">
        </form></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha...!

I fixed the code by writing another route for the delete button

```
@app.route('/users', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def users():
    if request.form:
        user_db = Users(user_name = request.form.get("user_name"),
                        age = request.form.get("age"),
                        gender=request.form.get("gender"),
                        activeness=request.form.get("activeness")
                        )
        db.session.add(user_db)
        db.session.commit()
    user_data = Users.query.all()
    return render_template("users.html", user_data = user_data)

@app.route('/delete_users', methods=["POST"])
def delete_user():
    if request.form:
        user_db = Users.query.filter_by(user_id=request.form.get("user_id")).first()
        db.session.delete(user_db)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect("/users")
```